# Dateetry tkinter date format error in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem entering the date with the date entry, when I enter 1999 or earlier it shows the year 2000 onwards, for example, when I enter **January 10, 1997**, it returns **10/01/2097**. How can I fix this, please help me, thanks a lot

```
dayOfbirh = StringVar()
c_birth = '%m-%d-%y'
label7 = Label(frame,textvariable=dayOfbirh)
dayOfbirh.set("DayOfBirth")
label7.place(x =0 ,y =180)
ent7 = DateEntry(frame,textvariable=c_birth,background="blue",foreground="white",borderwidth = 2,width=37)
ent7.place(x =70 ,y =180)
```

Comment: Try using `ent7._date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date_pattern`. It is inbuilt parameter for `DateEntry` and you can give your date pattern as `c_birth = 'm/d/y'`.

Please check the snippet

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from tkinter import *
frame = tk.Tk()

def getdt(arg=None): 
    result = ent7.get()
    label7.config(text=result)
    ent7.delete(0,END)
    
c_birth = 'm/d/y'
ent7=DateEntry(frame, date_pattern=c_birth)
ent7.pack()
label7 = Label(frame,text=" ")
label7.pack()
btn = Button(frame, text= "Enter", command=getdt)
btn.pack()
frame.mainloop()
```

For more details about `date_pattern` you can refer [tkCalendar](https://readthedocs.org/projects/tkcalendar/downloads/pdf/latest/) page 10